# Creating an increasing list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-2.7

I am trying to create some lists from other lists putting some conditions along the way. I want to write these lists finally into a csv. Here is the code which I attempted.

```
x = [None]*1000
y = [None]*1000
z = [None]*1000
i = 0 
for d in range(0,len(productID)):
    for j in range(0,len(productID[d])):
        if productID[d][j].startswith(u'sku'):

            x[i] = map[productID[d][j]]
            y[i] = name[d]
            z[i] = priceID[d][productID[d][j]].get(u'e')

            i = i + 1  

plan_name = x[0:i]
dev_name  = y[0:i]
dev_price = z[0:i]
```

This is working fine, but I assume there should be a better way of doing this. Can anyone suggest how can I create a list while looping without having to define it first?

Comment: Have a list of tuples or dictionaries instead of three different lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `.append()` to add items to an initially empty list instead.

```
x, y, z = [], [], []
for d, sublist in enumerate(productID):
    for entry in sublist:
        if entry.startswith(u'sku'):
            x.append(map[entry])
            y.append(name[d])
            z.append(priceID[d][entry].get(u'e'))
```

Note that python can loop over sequences directly, and you usually do not need indexes at all. I've used the `enumerate()` function to add indexes to the outer loop instead (because you seem to need to index into `name` and `priceID` there).

`.append()` adds items to the end of the list:

```
>>> foo = []
>>> foo.append('bar')
>>> foo.append('spam')
>>> foo
['bar', 'spam']
```

You may want to read over the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/); it explains how python lists work nicely.